# SQL create table syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I do not undertstand what is the problem with this:

```
CREATE TABLE 'posts' (
  'IdPost' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'IdUser' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'name' varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  'title' varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  'type' tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  'address' varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  'lat' varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  'lon' varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  'url' varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('IdPost')
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

I am getting this error on my server:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''posts' ( 'IdPost' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'IdUser' int(11) NOT NUL' at line 1
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the quotes for your table name. Also remove all the quotes from your column name too.

**[DEMO SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d988d)**

**On a side note:-**

From [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2036581&seqNum=2):-

> Quoting is useful when an identifier is an SQL reserved word or
>   contains spaces or other special characters. Quoting an identifier
>   also enables it to be entirely numeric, something not true of unquoted
>   identifiers. To include an identifier quote character within a quoted
>   identifier, double it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put your table or column names in quotes. You have to use backticks for [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) which is not the case for this table.

```
CREATE TABLE posts 
(
  IdPost int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  IdUser int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  title varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  type tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  address varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  lat varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  lon varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  url varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (IdPost)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: I think the general best practice is to use backticks, regardless of reserved words.

Comment: I disagree. I use it only for reserved words.

Comment: Debatable: if something isn't a reserved word now, it can become a reserved word in a newer MySQL version (`PARTITION` for instance in 5.6). Which means you have to update your statements if a new version comes out. I do tend to omit the backticks, but only because I usually don't write software 3rd parties are going to use, internal only, so I/we control both the code we use & the versions of software.

Answer (score 0):

This can be an alternative:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
`IdPost` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`IdUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`lat` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`lon` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`IdPost`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

I would suggest to use `back tilts` instead of `quotes`